# Linux Sed | awk | cut |trim

Tags: linux, sed

Actually the file is like bmb/case.bmb

I want the output like bmx/eng/case.bmx

I am using the below command

```bash
$ sed "s/bmb/bmx\/eng/g" 
bmx/eng/case.bmx/eng
```

Can you please help me in removing the `/eng` from the command by adding `awk`/`cut`/`trim` or any command

Comment: but: your `sed` is actively **adding** the `/eng`. So, just don't add the /eng in the `sed` program? Do you *understand* what your `sed` invocation does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(bm)b/\1x/g;s~/~&eng&~' input_file
bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

Comment: Thanks Hatless , Command is working perfectly .
One more i need can i get the  orginal file name along with the replacement file name 
output like:
bmb/case.bmb
bmx/eng/case.bmx

Comment: @afrin That sounds like a different question. Maybe open a new question for it. You can try `sed -E 's/.*/& &/;:a;s/([^ ]* [^\n]*)(bm)b/\1\2x/;ta;s~/~&eng&~2' input_file`

Comment: This is working but it is creating 1 more duplicate file for other files as well afile afile bfile bfile   bmb/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx

Comment: Please answer my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/748320/revisions

Comment: $ echo bmb/case.bmb  | sed -E 's/.*/& &/;:a;s/([^ ]* [^\n]*)(bm)b/\1\2x/;ta;s~/~&eng&~2'
bmb/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx

Above command works